# Add items to a Thumb dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I created a two thumbs dynamically that look like rectangles and handled the drag and drop events so they can move inside a Canvas. Later when I press some button on the UI, I want to add some strings dynamically to each Thumb inside the Canvas. Is there a way to do it. Please help.

Xaml:

```
 <uwpControls:LayoutTransformControl x:Name="MainLayoutControl" Grid.Row="4" Height="400" Width="600" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <Grid Grid.Row="4" x:Name="gridBarImagePanel"  BorderBrush="Black" 
                      BorderThickness="2">

                        <Image x:Name="BarCodeImage" 
                               RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"></Image>

                        <Canvas x:Name="cnvBarCodeImage">

                        </Canvas>
                    </Grid>
                </uwpControls:LayoutTransformControl>
```

Code Behind:

```
 private void CreateUIShapes(int numberOfWindows, List<Dimensions> dimensions)
        {
            Thumb th = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfWindows; i++)
            {
                th = new Thumb();
                th.Name = i.ToString();
                var item = dimensions[i];
                th.Width = item.Width;
                th.Height = item.Height;
                th.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Transparent);
                th.BorderBrush = item.BorderColor;
                th.BorderThickness = new Thickness(3);
                th.DragDelta += (sender, e) => Th_DragDelta(sender, e, dimensions);
                th.DragCompleted += (sender, e) => Th_DragCompleted(sender, e, item.IsImageRotated);
                //RotateWindowsByAngle(90, th, dimensions, i);
                Canvas.SetLeft(th, item.left);
                Canvas.SetTop(th, item.Top);
                cnvBarCodeImage.Children.Add(th);
            }
        }

        private void BtnScan_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //How can I add some text to the Thumb controls at this point. There is no Children Property.

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `Thumb` isn't a `ContentControl`, you will have to supply it with a custom `ControlTemplate` to add text to it.

Here is a simple example showing how to do this in code:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
using System.Windows.Markup;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace WpfApp4
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var thumb = new Thumb
            {
                Width = 100, 
                Height = 50, 
                Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red), 
                Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White), 
                Template = GetThumbTemplate("")
            };

            Canvas.SetLeft(thumb, 100);
            Canvas.SetTop(thumb, 100);

            RootCanvas.Children.Add(thumb);

            thumb.Template = GetThumbTemplate("Hello world!");
        }

        private ControlTemplate GetThumbTemplate(string text)
        {
            var template = "<ControlTemplate xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\" TargetType=\"Thumb\">" +
                           "<Border Background=\"{TemplateBinding Background}\">" +
                           "<TextBlock VerticalAlignment=\"Center\" HorizontalAlignment=\"Center\" Text=\"" + text + "\" />" +
                           "</Border>" +
                           "</ControlTemplate>";

            return XamlReader.Parse(template) as ControlTemplate;
        }
    }
}
```

When I create the `Thumb` I set the `Template` with `GetThumbTemplate` and pass in an empty string. `GetThumbTemplate` creates a simple `ControlTemplate` with a `Border` and a `TextBlock`. I then parse the XAML and return it.

After I add it to the `Canvas`, I update the `Template` of the `Thumb` using the `GetThumbTemplate` method, passing in the string I want to display.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you @Keithernet that helps. Problem is when I initially say Template = GetThumbTemplate("") then I don't see any Thumb controls being displayed on the UI.

Comment: Firstly I commented out emplate = GetThumbTemplate("") line.  Now when I put a breakpoint at the Scan Button Click, then I am able to see some Template already being applied to the Thumb control. Is there a way to add elements to that existing Template.

Comment: Thanks that gives me an idea. I can try to fix it.